# How do I use dependency injection in a custom Laravel package?

Tags: laravel

**Question**

When creating a custom Laravel package, should I have access to other classes via constructor dependency injection?

**Background**

I am creating a Laravel package.

I have created a local repo with my code in which is linked to in my Laravel composer file.

`laravel/composer.json`

```
    "repositories": {
        "local": {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../packages/blog"
        }
    }
```

In the package, I have my composer.json created two simple classes:

`package/composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "namespace/blog",
    "description": "Quick blog",
    "type": "library",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Namespace\\Blog\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Bob Blog",
            "email": "bob@blog.com"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Namespace\\Blog\\BlogServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    },
    "require": {}
}
```

Reader.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Blog;

class Reader
{
    public function loadFiles()
    {
        dd('show me');
    }
}
```

And then I have a blog class, in which I would like to inject my reader class:

```
namespace Namespace\Blog;

class Blog
{
    private $reader;

    /**
    * PLEASE INJECT READER INSTANCE HERE!
    */
    public function __construct(Reader $reader)
    {
        $this->reader = $reader;
    }

    public function list()
    {
        $this->reader->loadFiles();
    }
}
```

In my Laravel app, I try to call the package like so:

```
$blog = new \Namespace\Blog();
```

But I get the following error:

```
Too few arguments to function Namespace\Blog\Blog::__construct(), 0 passed
```

Do I need to actually register any classes I want to inject in the service container? I thought Laravel created these automatically if they were concrete classes....

Comment: That's not injection, that's simply type hinting at that point. I don't know what kind of Magic Laravel does behind the scenes to "inject" things like `public function index(Request $request)`, but for your case, you'd have to do `$blog = new Blog(new Reader(...))`, or omit it from your arguments `__construct()` and simply do `$this->reader = new Reader(...);`. Or, you can dig through Laravel's SRC to see how Controllers and what-not do it, and try to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops. The problem was I was instantiating the class cold, ie:

```
$blog = new \Namespace\Blog();
```

Which obviously is passing no arguments.

In order for dependencies to be injected, this class also needs injecting into the a controller, eg

```
public function blogController(\Namespace\Blog $blog) {
    // I now have a blog instance at $blog
}

Doh!
```